# Referencing class resource in FXML

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have a JavaFX program that uses Maven, with a standard maven file tree:

[image]

How do I reference logo.png from within layout.fxml, assuming that layout is being inflated by a call to

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/layout.fxml"));
```

in `MainApp`.

I've trying to do so using

```
<image>
<Image url="@/graphics/logo.png" />
</image>
```

and have tried many variations on that file path (with and without the `@`), but keep throwing a

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
... 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must not be empty
```

on the line where the URL is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to locate the image resource with name "backButton.png" whereas it should be "logo.png".

If the problem persists, try as

```
<Image url="@../graphics/logo.png" />
```

since from [official FXML tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution):

> The location resolution operator (represented by an "@" prefix to the
>   attribute value) is used to specify that an attribute value should be
>   treated as a location **relative** to the **current file** rather than a
>   simple string.

Comment: The filename was just a typo here, it's correct in my program. Your suggestion did not help, however. I'm afraid this is caused by the fact that, if `@` is relative to the fxml file, `graphics` is not accessible as a child folder. It's a sibling of the fxml folder under the parent `resources` folder.

Comment: @drewmore, ".." means the parent folder of the current location, i.e. the parent folder of FXML folder. So the path "../graphics" is correct. To confirm the package structure, unzip the produced jar file and check the folders and the location of the mentioned image in them.

Comment: Hey why -1. Can the one who did it explain the reason of his/her act?