# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException javafx

Tags: javafx

I write program with java8, JAVAFX, spring, hibernate, jpa, mysql.
I've to problem with connecting server part of program with javafx.

When I click on class with main→run as java aplication, this problems occurs:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Sylwia/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Sylwia/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Sylwia/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.5.8/slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1732398722.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Sylwia/git/Praca%20inzynierska%203/Praca%20inzynierska%202/target/classes/fxml/productComponent.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at pl.ftims.praca.restClientJavafx.RestClient.start(RestClient.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1441419654.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/742445343.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.ftims.praca.restClientJavafx.FXMLController.initialize(FXMLController.java:140)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application pl.ftims.praca.restClientJavafx.RestClient
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Should I first focus on problem:

```
at pl.ftims.praca.restClientJavafx.RestClient.start(RestClient.java:17)
```

or:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.ftims.praca.restClientJavafx.FXMLController.initialize(FXMLController.java:140)
    ... 23 more
```

my RestClient class:

```
package pl.ftims.praca.restClientJavafx;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RestClient extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        //When using the Class.getResource method, 
        //you must provide a local path from the location of the class on which is called the method.
        //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(RestClient.class.getResource("/fxml/components.fxml"));
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(RestClient.class.getResource("/fxml/productComponent.fxml"));
        //I also had to use Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
        
        /*FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoadergetClass().getResource("main.fxml");
loader.setController(new MainController(path));
Pane mainPane = loader.load();*/        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FXMLController class

```
package pl.ftims.praca.restClientJavafx;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import pl.ftims.praca.model.ProductWrapper;
import pl.ftims.praca.model.Products;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView productTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn idColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn nameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn sellingPriceColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn purchasePriceColumn;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField idField;//tego nie bylo chyba, bo nie mozna przeciez zmieniac id
    @FXML
    private TextField nameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField sellingPriceField;
    @FXML
    private TextField purchasePriceField;
/*private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Double sellingPrice;
    private Double purchasePrice; //cena zakupu
    @ManyToOne
    private Storages storage; */
    
    private List<Products> listOfProducts = null;
    private List<Fxproduct> listOfFxProducts = null;
    private ObservableList<Fxproduct> listOfObservableList = null;
    private final static String REST_ROOT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/rest/";
    private final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    @FXML
    private void remove(ActionEvent event) { //ok rozumiem

        Fxproduct fxproduct = (Fxproduct) productTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        listOfObservableList.remove(fxproduct);

        Response response = client.target(REST_ROOT_URL).
//                path("publisher").
                path("products").
                path("deleteProductWithId").
                path(String.valueOf(fxproduct.getId())).
                request().delete();
    }

    @FXML
    private void save(ActionEvent event) {
        Products product = new Products();
        product.setName(nameField.getText());
        product.setPurchasePrice(Double.parseDouble(purchasePriceField.getText()));
        product.setSellingPrice(Double.parseDouble(sellingPriceField.getText()));

        Entity<Products> kitapEntity = Entity.entity(product, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        Response response = client.target(REST_ROOT_URL).
                path("product").
                path("createProductWithData").
                request().
                post(kitapEntity);

        list(null);
        nameField.setText("");
        purchasePriceField.setText("");
        sellingPriceField.setText("");
    }

    @FXML
    private void list(ActionEvent event) { //NIE WIEM JAK TO ZROBIC

        Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest/").
                path("products").
                path("products").
                request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
                get();
        ProductWrapper productWrapper = response.readEntity(ProductWrapper.class); //nie mam tego



        listOfProducts = (productWrapper.getProductList()==null)?new ArrayList<Products>(): productWrapper.getProductList();

//        listOfFxProducts = new ArrayList<>();
//        listOfFxProducts = new ArrayList<>(); //tak bylo, ale to jest java 1.7 i  sie nie kompilowalo

        
        for (Products k : listOfProducts) {
            listOfFxProducts.add(new Fxproduct(k));
        }

        listOfObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(listOfFxProducts);
        System.out.println(listOfObservableList);
        productTable.setItems(listOfObservableList);
        System.out.println(productTable);

    }

    public void kitapDuzenle(Products product) {

        Entity<Products> kitapEntity = Entity.entity(product, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        Response response = client.target(REST_ROOT_URL).
                path("product").
                path("saveProduct2").
                request().
                put(kitapEntity);

    }

//    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        productTable.setEditable(true); //tu jest blad, nullpointer

        //NAME
        nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        nameColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Fxproduct, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Fxproduct, String> t) {
                        ObservableList<Fxproduct> kitapListesi = t.getTableView().getItems();
                        Fxproduct kitap = kitapListesi.get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());
                        kitap.setName(t.getNewValue());
                        kitapDuzenle(kitap.getproduct());
                    }
                }
                );
        
        //SELLINGPRICE
        sellingPriceColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleToStringConverter()));//tu jest blad
        sellingPriceColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Fxproduct, Double>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Fxproduct, Double> t) {
                        ObservableList<Fxproduct> kitapListesi = t.getTableView().getItems();
                        Fxproduct kitap = kitapListesi.get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());
                        kitap.setSellingPrice(t.getNewValue()); //tu ejst problem z double i siple double
                        kitapDuzenle(kitap.getproduct());
                    }
                }
                );
        
        //PURCHASEPRICE
        purchasePriceColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleToStringConverter()));
        purchasePriceColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Fxproduct, Double>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Fxproduct, Double> t) {
                        ObservableList<Fxproduct> kitapListesi = t.getTableView().getItems();
                        Fxproduct kitap = kitapListesi.get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());
                        kitap.setPurchasePrice(t.getNewValue());//tu ejst problem z double i siple double
                        kitapDuzenle(kitap.getproduct());
                    }
                }
                );

        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Fxproduct, Long>("id"));
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Fxproduct, String>("name"));
        purchasePriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Fxproduct, Double>("price"));
        sellingPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Fxproduct, Double>("price"));

        list(null);

    }
}
```

I thought that the problems is the path:
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(RestClient.class.getResource("/fxml/productComponent.fxml"));
but I read this:

[How to reference javafx fxml files in resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder)

[JavaFX "Location is required." even though it is in the same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package)

[Referencing class resource in FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618596/referencing-class-resource-in-fxml)

[Error loading fxml files from a folder other than the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785919/error-loading-fxml-files-from-a-folder-other-than-the-bin-folder)

[JavaFX: load resource from other package - NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452254/javafx-load-resource-from-other-package-netbeans)

[How to reference javafx fxml files in resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602727/how-to-reference-javafx-fxml-files-in-resource-folder)

https://stackexchange.com/search?q=How+to+reference+javafx+fxml+files+in+resource+folder%3F

[JavaFX - Exception in Application start method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451990/javafx-exception-in-application-start-method)
and I didnt find the answer.
/////////////////////////////EDIT///////////////////

```
line 17 in RestClient: 
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(RestClient.class.getResource("/fxml/productComponent.fxml")); 


line 139, 140 in FXMLController: 
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { productTable.setEditable(true); // nullpointer
```

Comment: The `start()` method loads the FXML (I am guessing that is line 17), during which the `FXMLLoader` calls the `initialize()` method. So the problem is in the `initialize()` method. Which line is line 140 in the controller?

Comment: line 17 in RestClient:  Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(RestClient.class.getResource("/fxml/productComponent.fxml"));  line 139, 140 in FXMLController:   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        productTable.setEditable(true); // nullpointer

Comment: So `productTable` is not initialized. You probably have an error in the mapping between the FXML `fx:id` and the field name in the controller. Post the portion of the FXML file where the `productTable` is declared.